# Apply filter stored in string format on a pandas data frame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe which is as follows:

```
KeyColumn Column2 Column3 Column4 

pk1    abc    def      col4        
pk2    col3    col1    col4        
pk2    col4    col2    col4        
pk4    col5    col4    col4         
pk5    col6    col5    col4          
pk6    col7    col6    col4           
pk7    col8    col7    col4           
pk8    col9    col8    col4            
pk9    col10   col9    col4             
pk10   col11   col3    col4
```

when i apply a filter on it like following:

```
dataframe[(dataframe['Column2']=='abc') & (dataframe['Column3']=='def')]
```

I get the intended result. But,  the filter that i have applied is available with me in the form of a string variable.

for example:

```
filterParameters = "(dataframe['Column2']=='abc') & (dataframe['Column3']=='def')"
```

When I pass the variable to the dataframe as filter

```
dataframe[filterParameters]
```

I get the error

KeyError: "(dataframe['Column1']=='abc') & (dataframe['Column2']=='def')"

Please let me know if anyone can help. Thanks a lot.

Comment: You could use `dataframe[eval(filterParameters)]`, though I am not a fan of using `eval` like this.

Comment: Where do you get this string from? Do you construct it yourself? Try and avoid `eval` if possible, it poses security risks.

Comment: Thanks James for the help and yes I have to construct it myself.

Answer (score 0):

Pandas has an `eval` method you can use to evaluate the filter strings, but you need to be damned sure what you are evaluating is sanitized.  Using `eval` on anything you did not construct yourself is risky.

```
import pandas as pd

dataframe = pd.DataFrame([['pk1','abc','def','col4'],
    ['pk2','col3','col1','col4'],
    ['pk2','col4','col2','col4'],
    ['pk4','col5','col4','col4'],
    ['pk5','col6','col5','col4'],
    ['pk6','col7','col6','col4'],
    ['pk7','col8','col7','col4'],
    ['pk8','col9','col8','col4'],
    ['pk9','col10','col9','col4'],
    ['pk10','col11','col3','col4']], 
    columns=['KeyColumn','Column2','Column3','Column4'])

filterParameters = "(dataframe['Column2']=='abc') & (dataframe['Column3']=='def')"

dataframe[pd.eval(filterParameters)]
```